in codesandbox.io devtool console panel, when console.log( an Object ) in setInterval's callback， it will print twice the same content
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/holy-water-s548tn
let i = 0;
setInterval(() => {
    console.log(i++, {});
}, 1000);

it will be prince {} twice every time excute console.log
Anyone can tell me why?
if console.log non-object , just like 1 or "string" etc, it will print once every time.
